# jQuery UI Slider using range, strange behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code and I have problem with jQuery UI Slider. What is my problem:

While the slider is rendered correctly, it acting very strange. What do I mean? Instead of rendering to handlers it is rendering only one, and the slider can slide only until the value 70 witch is the second value into my array. Any idea please on how to solve that problem ?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<td valign="top">
    <input 
        class="slider_hidden" 
        type="hidden"
        name="field_name" 
        value="10,70" 
        id="slider_hidden" 
        data-disabled="0"
        data-min="0"
        data-max="100"
        data-orientation="horizontal"
        data-step="1"
        data-range="1"
    />
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <br />
    <span class="description"><?php echo $description; ?></span>
</td>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $(".slider").each(
            function()
            {
                var val = $(this).prev('input.slider_hidden').val();
                var min = $(this).prev('input.slider_hidden').data('min');
                var max = $(this).prev('input.slider_hidden').data('max');
                var step = $(this).prev('input.slider_hidden').data('step');
                var slide_disabled = ($(this).prev('input.slider_hidden').data('disabled') == "1" ? true : false);
                var orientation = $(this).prev('input.slider_hidden').data('orientation');
                var range = ($(this).prev('input.slider_hidden').data('range') == "1" ? true : false);

                $(this).slider(
                    {
                        min: min,
                    max: max,
                        step: step,
                        disabled: slide_disabled,
                        orientation: orientation,
                        slide: function(e, ui)
                        {
                            console.log(ui);
                            $(this).prev('input.slider_hidden').val(ui.value);
                        }
                    }
                );

                $(this).slider('option', 'range', range);

                if(range == true)
                {
                    var s = val.split(',');
                    $(this).slider("option", "values", s);
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).slider("option", "value", val);
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Note that all values are retrived correctly from hidden field.

Comment: You should at least save `$(this)` (and `.prev()` as well while you're doing it) inside a variable to speed up your code.

Comment: It seems like using the range: "min". Any idea, or what may I have wrong with that ? :?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long investigation, it seems you can set `values` or `value` once it has been initialized !

So I've found no others solutions than doing this : http://jsfiddle.net/7YVVY/1/

It works, but it is not elegant :)

Comment: One uprate only for your try :) I will read the code and I will mark as answer if correct :) Thanks a lot Guillaume Cisco ! :)

Comment: @MerianosNikos: I updated the code a bit, to make it simpler (and faster): http://jsfiddle.net/7YVVY/3/ I'm sure Guillaume won't mind. ;)

Comment: @MerianosNikos: It's also interesting that a further simplification (without an `if` statement) can be made. Providing both properties (`values` and `value`) doesn't hurt. Slider will use the one based on `range` property value. Interesting and utterly simplified. http://jsfiddle.net/7YVVY/4/